# Recursive VBA Function

Tags: excel, vba, recursion

I am trying to program a recursive function in VBA so that once the function I have created starts increasing, the result is capped at the lowest point.

The code I have written so far is:

```
Public Function function2(var1, var2, var3, var4)

temp = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(var3- 1, 2)

function_temp = function1(var1,var2, temp, var4)


If function_temp < function1(var1, var2, var3, var4) Then function2= function_temp 

If function_temp >= function1(var1, var2, var3, var4) Then function2= function1(var1, var2, var3, var4)

End Function
```

Here is what the numbers look like, with the Desired column what I want ultimately.

```
Duration    Result  Current Desired

2   2.845   2.845   2.845

3   2.563   2.563   2.563

4   2.371   2.371   2.371

5   2.252   2.252   2.252

6   2.189   2.189   2.189

7   2.170   2.170   2.170

8   2.182   2.170   2.170

9   2.213   2.182   2.170

10  2.246   2.213   2.170

11  2.259   2.246   2.170

12  2.241   2.241   2.170
```

I realize I need to use a recursive function, but I can't sort it out. Any thoughts? thanks.

Comment: Hey @dc2 , if this is in excel you can use =min(cell1,cell2,cellAbove)... does that work?

Comment: No, I need it coded in VBA, as the values change.

Comment: So I guess I don't understand what you are doing then- is your data in excel? Both current and desired? So you are writing a UDF or a sub? Just unclear on what you are trying to do...

Comment: Hi, the data is being output by another function I have written in VBA. The result is the output of that function  (function1). The current column is the current output with my code trying to fix the problem. I need the the output to look like the desired column however.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "the result is capped at the lowest point".  The lowest point of what?  Also, is this being *used* as a UDF - i.e. do you have cells where you've used `function2` in the cell's formula?

Comment: Yes, it is being used as a UDF. Basically these points create a curve, and I don't want the curve to start increasing. I want it to stay flat. So the function once it outputs 2.170 shouldn't then increase to 2.182, but stay flat thereafter at 2.170.

Comment: I don't see why you need recursion - Assuming the results column starts in C2 then enter =Function1(var1,var2,var3,var4) in C2 and then enter =MIN(C2,Function1(var1,var2,var3,var4)) in C3 and copy down

Answer (score 0):

Just create a variable that can hold the minimum value? Let's say, minVar.

If the result is larger than the minimum, then use the minVar.
If the result is lower than the minimum, then use the value and overwrite the minVar.

```
Dim minVar as double
minVar = 999999    
If function_temp < function1(var1, var2, var3, var4) 
        Then  if function_temp < minVar
                 Then minVar = function_temp
               end if
         temp function2= function_temp
 end if
```

Comment: Right, I would do that, except the minimum changes and there is no way to calculate the minimum. The formula has 4 inputs, so the minimum changes depending upon the inputs.